# scipy: finding optimal parameters with fmin and odeint, bad fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Below I solve a second order ODE that describes a spring-mass dashpot system: u'' +c*u'+k*u=0. I have no problems with the odeint solver.The odeint function correctly solves the position U(t) over the specified time.

```
#modeling spring mass system
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy import integrate

#Make the following substitution to make system first order
#Y[1]=y′(t) and Y[0]=y(t),
#system: Y[0]'=Y[1] and Y[1]'=-c*Y[1]-k*Y[0]


#=======================================================
def eq(par,initial_cond,start_t,end_t,incr):
     #-time-grid-----------------------------------
     t  = np.linspace(start_t, end_t,incr)
     #differential-eq-system----------------------
     def funct(y,t):
        ut=y[0]
        ut_dt=y[1]
        c,k=par
        # the model equations u'=Y[1], u''=-k*Y[0]-c*Y[1] from u''+c*u'+k*u=0
        f0 =ut_dt
        f1 =-k*ut-c*ut_dt
        return [f0, f1]
     #integrate------------------------------------
     ds = integrate.odeint(funct,initial_cond,t)
     return (ds[:,0],ds[:,1],t)
#=======================================================

#parameters   
c=2. #spring coefficient 
k=10. #dampening coefficient

#collect parameters in tuple
coefs=(c,k)

# initial conditions

u0=6.
ud0=0.
y0=[u0,ud0]

start,stop,incr=0,20,100

#Solve and plot solution
F0,F1,T=eq(coefs,y0,start,stop,incr)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(T,F0,'-b',T,F1,'-r')
plt.legend(('u0', 'u1'),'upper center')
plt.title('Mass-Spring System')
```

However, I would like to use scipy.optimize.fmin() to find the optimal fitting parameters (c,k) for this system if given simulated measurements. So I use the solution from above where c=2, and k=10 and add random noise.

```
rand_i=randn(incr)
#noiselevel
nl=.05
noisy_data=F0+nl*rand_i
plt.plot(noisy_data,label="noisy_data:c=2,k=10")
plt.legend()
```

Next, I set up a scoring function for fmin() to minimize. I use a guess for the parameters, c=1,k=1.

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin

#1.Get 'Real' Data
#====================================================
nd=noisy_data#solution with parameters: c=2,k=10
#====================================================

#2.Set up Info for Model System
#===================================================
# guess parameters   
c=1 #spring coefficient 
k=1 #dampening coefficient

#collect parameters in tuple
coefs=(c,k)

# initial conditions
u0=6.
ud0=0.
y0=[u0,ud0]

# model steps
#---------------------------------------------------
start_time=0
end_time=20
intervals=100
mt=np.linspace(start_time,end_time,intervals)

#3.Score Fit of System
#=========================================================
def score(parms):
    #a.Get Solution to system
    F0,F1,T=eq(coefs,y0,start_time,end_time,intervals)
    #b.Pick of Model Points to Compare
    um=F0
    #c.Score Difference between model(ode output) and data points (noisy data)
    ss=lambda data,model:((data-model)**2).sum()
    return ss(nd,um)
#========================================================


#4.Optimize Fit
#=======================================================
fit_score=score(coefs)
answ=fmin(score,(coefs))
```

The problem is that fmin doesn't find the correct parameters. It finds that the guess parameters are the best, even though the score function is high. Below I print the fmin solution answ and show that it is the same as the initial guess even after fmin() has been called.

```
print(answ==[c,k])
```

Does anyone know why fmin() doesn't find the correct parameters, c=2, k=10?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the analytic solution as a fitting model?

Comment: I understand your question as: why not use the analytic solution as a fitting model rather than the analytic solution + noise? I could have done that, but I want to test the ability of fmin() to find the optimal parameters with increasing noise. However, you are correct that as a test, it is probably better to test the analytic solution first. Thanks for your input and help!

Comment: No, I meant why not fit the analytic solution (`exp(-c/2*t)*(A*cos(w*t)+B*sin(w*t))` with `w=sqrt(k-c^2/4)`) to the simulated noisy data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trivial bug in your code: you define `score` with input parameter `parms`, but then refer to said variable as `coefs`. Fix:

```
def score(coefs): #changed
    #a.Get Solution to system
    F0,F1,T=eq(coefs,y0,start_time,end_time,intervals)
    #b.Pick of Model Points to Compare
    um=F0
    #c.Score Difference between model(ode output) and data points (noisy data)
    ss=lambda data,model:((data-model)**2).sum()
    return ss(nd,um)
```

Before:

```
In [369]: answ
Out[369]: array([ 1.,  1.])
```

After:

```
In [373]: answ
Out[373]: array([ 2.0425695 ,  9.96937966])
```

However, note that `answ==(c,k)` will *always* be `False`, even for a perfect fit: you're working with floating-point numbers. Any meaningful comparison should look like `max(abs(answ-[2,10])/abs(answ))<tol` or something similar. (I know your original question used this to show that the values *didn't* change, but still.)

Comment: Thanks! you got it. And your correct that answ==(c,k) is not a way to check that it works, but rather a way to illustrate the bug. Thanks again!